# Errors encountered while processing linux-firmware, linux-image-raspi, linux-raspi, and initramfs-tools on RasPi Zero W2 Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, kernel, dpkg

I installed and configured WiFi on a Raspberry Pi Zero W 2 running Ubuntu 21.10 Server. I ran `apt update` and then `apt upgrade` with the below output.  It's a brand new board and a fresh installation so I'm not sure at all what might be going on.

`sudo apt upgrade`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu6) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-firmware (1.201.1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-1008-raspi
Killed
E: mkinitramfs failure zstd -q -19 -T0 137
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-1008-raspi with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-raspi:
 linux-image-raspi depends on linux-firmware; however:
  Package linux-firmware is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-raspi (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-5.13.0-1011-raspi (5.13.0-1011.13) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-raspi:
 linux-raspi depends on linux-image-raspi (= 5.13.0.1011.17); however:
  Package linux-image-raspi is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package linux-raspi (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu6) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-1008-raspi
Killed
E: mkinitramfs failure zstd -q -19 -T0 137
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-1008-raspi with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.13.0-1011-raspi (5.13.0-1011.13) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-1011-raspi
Killed
E: mkinitramfs failure zstd -q -19 -T0 137
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-1011-raspi with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.13.0-1011-raspi (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.13.0-1011-raspi package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
 linux-image-raspi
 linux-raspi
 initramfs-tools
 linux-image-5.13.0-1011-raspi
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about the exact actions you were taking when you "configured WiFi" -- if this is the only thing that you did after a clean installation, then that's probably the cause of your problems

Comment: Your system has messed up! It is recommended to do a fresh install!

Comment: can you please post the output of `sudo apt -f install`

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue on a Pi Zero 2 using 64-bit Ubuntu Server 21.10.  Unless you have a swapfile enabled, the update process can run out of memory.

Example swapfile creation -

```
sudo fallocate -l 1G /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
echo "/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

Reference: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Comment: Spot on..  I've seen this error on a 1GB CM4 as well..

Answer (score 1):

Your system has messed up, I doubt that it is a fresh install as this problem should not be there on a fresh install, anyways, I would recommend reinstalling as the first choice but if you cannot then here is an answer which may help you to get out of these errors.

## Note

- I am **putting "*" after every solution** that will most probably work.

#### Short answer *

Simple remove and reinstall packages:-

You can remove the packages by:-

```
$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq linux-firmware
$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq linux-image-raspi
$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq linux-raspi
$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq initramfs-tools
$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq linux-image-5.13.0-1011-raspi
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

Then reinstall them

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware linux-image-raspi linux-raspi initramfs-tools  linux-image-5.13.0-1011-raspi
```

---

### Advanced solutions:-

#### Using force install. *

Generally, using `apt -f install` works! 
Run:

```
sudo apt -f install
```

If the error is fixed then congratulations but if not then proceed.

#### Going a little advance *

You may want to clear the cache files of `apt` to fix this issue. Generally, it wouldn't harm your OS in any way.
You can run

```
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb
```

More likely, it will fix the error! If not then proceed.

#### Another solution.

You can try this also -

```
sudo -E apt-get install aptitude
sudo -E aptitude safe-upgrade
sudo -E aptitude dist-upgrade
```

After that

```
mkdir ~/debs
cd ~/debs
ls
sudo apt download linux-firmware linux-image-raspi linux-raspi initramfs-tools  linux-image-5.13.0-1011-raspi

sudo dpkg -i --force-all ./*.deb
```

#### Removing and reinstalling the packages.

You can remove the packages by:-

```
$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq linux-firmware
$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq linux-image-raspi
$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq linux-raspi
$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq initramfs-tools
$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq linux-image-5.13.0-1011-raspi
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

Then reinstall them

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware linux-image-raspi linux-raspi initramfs-tools  linux-image-5.13.0-1011-raspi
```

#### Last option *

As a last option, you could try removing the post-installation files of the error packages. This won't solve the error, but your system will ignore the errors.

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info/
mkdir ~/backup
mv linux-firmware ~/backup
mv linux-image-raspi ~/backup
mv linux-raspi ~/backup
mv initramfs-tools ~/backup
mv linux-image-5.13.0-1011-raspi ~/backup

sudo apt -f install
```

#### Did it work?

If it didn't work then there is no luck. **If these commands didn't work then your system is more messed up than it was before**. As you said, it is a fresh install so just reinstall ubuntu.

Comment: This is an OoM issue.

[ 1340.883260] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=user.slice,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-1.scope,task=zstd,pid=22733,uid=0
[ 1340.883402] Out of memory: Killed process 22733 (zstd) total-vm:499392kB, anon-rss:224628kB, file-rss:988kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:0 pgtables:500kB oom_score_adj:0
[ 1340.983190] oom_reaper: reaped process 22733 (zstd), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB

Comment: @funnsoup How is this a OOM issue?

Comment: Running the upgrade results in the OOM issue.