# failed update of linux-firmware and linux-image-5.4.0-105-generic

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, updates, dpkg

Motivated by a recent CVE security request to update the kernel I have tried to update my kernel with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install linux-generic` this has failed. So I have tried to update all the packages that were listed by `apt list --upgradable`.
This has not worked either.

At present if I try anything with apt, for instance `sudo dpkg --configure -a` I get a long amount of output, which ends with

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
 linux-image-5.4.0-105-generic
```

and somewhere in the middle contains a probably interesting message

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-1050-raspi
Using DTB: bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb
Installing /lib/firmware/5.4.0-1050-raspi/device-tree/bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb into /boot/dtbs/5.4.0-1050-raspi/./bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb
Taking backup of bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb.###############################################........................................................................................]
Installing new bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb.
Ignoring old or unknown version 5.4.0-1050-raspi (latest is 5.4.0-1055-raspi)
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-105-generic
Using DTB: bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb
Couldn't find DTB bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb on the following paths: /etc/flash-kernel/dtbs /usr/lib/linux-image-5.4.0-105-generic /lib/firmware/5.4.0-105-generic/device-tree/
Installing  into /boot/dtbs/5.4.0-105-generic/./bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb
cp: cannot stat '': No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//flash-kernel exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.4.0-105-generic (5.4.0-105.119) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-105-generic
Using DTB: bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb
Couldn't find DTB bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb on the following paths: /etc/flash-kernel/dtbs /usr/lib/linux-image-5.4.0-105-generic /lib/firmware/5.4.0-105-generic/device-tree/
Installing  into /boot/dtbs/5.4.0-105-generic/./bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb
cp: cannot stat '': No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//flash-kernel exited with return code 1
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.4.0-105-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.4.0-105-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for flash-kernel (3.103ubuntu1~20.04.3) ...
Using DTB: bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb
Installing /lib/firmware/5.4.0-1055-raspi/device-tree/bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb into /boot/dtbs/5.4.0-1055-raspi/./bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb
Taking backup of bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb.
Installing new bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb.
```

This system is `20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1050-raspi armv7l)` on a Raspberry Pi 2. Following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1380366/errors-encountered-while-processing-linux-firmware-linux-image-raspi-linux-ras) I have enlarged the swap.

I have also tried to clean my `boot` partition so to have room for the update. Right now I have 140+ Mb free `/dev/mmcblk0p1  253M  114M  139M  46% /boot/firmware` and plenty on `/`.

None of this helped.

I have tried to follow the security advice, now stuck with a half-broken system. Any idea on how to fix this and get the packages properly installed?

Comment: Why did you do the install of linux-generic instead of just doing an upgrade?

Comment: This was the command suggested by the sysadmin

Answer (score 0):

Recently I encountered a similar type of error on my ubuntu. I tried many things but could not get any help.
I checked the latest image for Linux by going into Advance boot options for ubuntu and found that linux-image-5.4.0-105-generic was a culprit and grub was not picking this entry by default. So, I have resolved the issue by choosing a previous image which is linux-image-5.4.0-104-generic and it is working fine for me. Don't know if Ubuntu is going to fix that issue with their release.

Comment: I have not rebooted still, so no issue with grub at the moment. Just annoyed that the apt systems is so not smart and breaks things ... "for humans"